# Limit SDL Publisher / Deployer packages in file size

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, web8.5, deployer

So our SDL editors have created some content pages stuffed with raw image material that they want to publish on our websites, of course everything into one single page.

I can see packages being generated that exceed 1gb in package size:
[image]

The publisher (Web 8.5, latest hotfixes) tried to transport the package to our CD environment where we have 1 Deployer, 4 Deployer Workers, ActiveMQ, Redis binary storage.

After 2 minutes, the Redis database will cut the connection due to 2 minute timeout setting resulting in deployer error message in core log.

```
2018-06-07 11:30:58,365 ERROR [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error] with root cause
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at redis.clients.util.RedisOutputStream.write(RedisOutputStream.java:50)
```

That behavior so far is expected:

```
<BinaryStorage Id="RedisStorage" Adapter="RedisBlobStorage">
    <Property Name="Host" Value="localhost"/>
    <Property Name="Port" Value="6379"/>
    <Property Name="Timeout" Value="120000"/>
</BinaryStorage>
```

I can also see the network traffic cutting completely for the time the process is waiting for Redis to timeout:

[image]

**So my question is:** Can i set a value somewhere that packages over 250mb are not being transported at all? This really large pages are blocking all other publish transactions for the time they are being stuck.

I tried setting the value in `application.properties` in deployer service:

```
# specifies the maximum size permitted for uploaded files.
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=250Mb
# specifies the maximum size allowed for multipart/form-data requests.
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=250Mb
```

Unfortunately without effect.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we still had no success with this problem. We resolved it with a new Template Building Block that simply let the page fail on rendering if there are `> 50` Components in a single page. Dirty solution but it did the job...